# Whenever gem NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nomethoderror, whenever

I am trying to make a functionality that sends emails at a specific time every day.
I am using the whenever gem with rails 4 but I can't get it work.

```
**schedule.rb**
     every 4.days do
        runner "User.reporting"
     end

**User.rb**
     def self.reporting
       users_size = 1
       ReportsMailer.reporting_users(users_size).deliver
     end
```

After running the "whenever --update-crontab" and "whenever" in terminal shows:

```
    0 0 1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29 * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/homes/HS && bin/rails runner -e production '\''User.reporting'\'''

    ## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file was not updated.
    ## [message] Run `whenever --help' for more options.
    You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

When restarting the **crond** I am running form my terminal:

```
    /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/homes/HS && bin/rails runner -e production '\''User.reporting'\'''
```

I get:

```
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53:in `eval': undefined method `reporting' for #<Class:0xc0028bc> (NoMethodError)
```

After this not only the mail is working but my facebook_omniauth gives me an error for the self.user_count_signin function:

```
    NoMethodError (private method `user_count_signin' called for #<User:0xc1549b8>):


app/controllers/access_controller.rb:58:in `facebook_connect'
```

This is in a production environment.

Comment: Try by removing self for the reporting method in your user.rb file like this `def reporting`

Comment: nothing changed. the server log shows the same error..

Comment: does your reporting method is calling?

Comment: sorry but I cant understand the question .. what do you mean calling?

Comment: I mean when the method is executing

Comment: No I think for some reason can not be found ...that's why tje NoMethodError

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63028/discussion-between-anusha-and-gematzab).